# Jmeter - Counter for double data type

Tags: java, automation, jmeter, automated-tests

I'm trying to automate a payment transaction wherein I need to increment a double data type value.

I used the Counter, but it seems it does not read an increment value with decimal. I set the following settings to Counter :

- Starting value of `1.04`
- Increment value of `0.01`

Same thing with Random Variable which my goal is to at least generate a random double or decimal value.

- Output format `00.00`
- Minimum value of `1`
- Maximum value of `5`

or even the settings below does not work.

- Output format `00.00`
- Minimum value of `1.00`
- Maximum value of `5.00`

Answer (score 0):

JMeter to my knowledge, unfortunately, doesn't support the decimal counters since they are of the `Long` type. From the [JMeter: Component reference: Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter):

> The counter uses a long to store the value, so the range is from -2^63 to 2^63-1.

**1. Generating a decimal number at all**

However, look a bit below to `format` description, which says the [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is used to form a String passed to the custom ex. `${counterA}` variable. See the *format* (emphasizes and highlighting mine):

> Optional format, e.g. 000 will format as 001, 002, etc. This is passed to `DecimalFormat`, so any valid formats can be used. If there is a problem interpreting the format, then it is ignored. [The default format is generated using Long.toString()]

This feature could be bend to your needs and it allows to add prefixes ([see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711406/jmeter-how-to-add-prefix-to-a-counter-similar-to-a-random-variable)) or suffixes to the generated value. Now it becomes a pure Java thing. Consider the variable `counter` is a `Long` generated with JMeter:

```
Long counter = 104L;
String string = new DecimalFormat("#,##").format(counter);  // 1,04
```

The conclusion is to use `#,##` Number format parameter within the Counter generation form. Now the configuration would look like:

- Minimum value: `104`
- Maximum value: `500`
- Increment value: `1`
- Number format: `#,##`

**2. Decimal separators `.` vs `,`**

The result becomes `1,04` with `0.01` increment value. Now the localization becomes the problem since some European countries use `.` as a separator of a decimal part and the second half uses `,` which is given by the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and it affects the [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)'s behavior. The only thing that left is to [Replace a substring in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137089/jmeter-how-can-i-replace-a-string-and-resend-it) using one of the pre-processors or configure the locale for JMeter (I have no experience with this).

**3. Performance matters, how about a CSV file then?**

Now you may ask whether the performance would be negatively affected using this workaround and whether the final results would be distorted. If used for the integration tests without measuring performance and generating results, I would not care at all. On the other hand, when the performance of the execution of the tests takes places, a better solution might be to load those pre-generated variables from an external file, such as CSV. Read more at [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use JSR223 Preprocessor to generate random numbers and then pass it further

[image]
Fetch using ${Random_Double}

Comment: It's a random number. Not a regularly incremented sequence of numbers.

Comment: Yes, Nikolas your are right..In the requirement, beef has written "my goal is to at least generate a random double or decimal value." So, I picked this up.